# How to make a nice matrix from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I would like to make a matrix that makes a list of nested dictionaries.
But I can't find out how to make a matrix, end even less how to put my values into it.

My dictionary looks like:

```
    {'1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
    '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
    '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
    '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
    '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
    '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}}
```

and it should be ordered in a matrix so it looks like this:

```
        1  2  3  4   5   6
     1  -  1  0  0   1   29
     2  13 -  1  0   21  0
     3  0  0  -  1   0   1
     4  1  17 1  -   2   0
     5  39 1  0  0   -   14
     6  0  0  43 1   0   -
```

I have only tried to understand how to make a matrix:

```
    table=[[for 0 in range(6)] for j in range[6]]
    print table
    for d1 in range(6):
        for d2 in range(6):
            table[d1][d2]=d1+d2+2
    print table
```

But I have a dictionary, not lists. I am really lost.

Comment: Show us your effort so far and we'll see where we can help.

Comment: Here's a start:  `print '  '.join('   ' + str(c) for c in range(1,7))`

Comment: I have put my effeort to make a matrix as an answer

Answer (score 16):

`import`**[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org)**`as pd`

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
                  '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
                  '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
                  '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
                  '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
                  '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}})
```

puts into `a`:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
1 NaN  13   0   1  39   0
2   1 NaN   0  17   1   0
3   0   1 NaN   1   0  43
4   0   0   1 NaN   0   1
5   1  21   0   2 NaN   0
6  29   0   1   0  14 NaN
```

which can be then printed into your format:

```
print a.to_string(na_rep='-')
```

printing:

```
    1   2   3  4   5   6
1   -   1   0  0   1  29
2  13   -   1  0  21   0
3   0   0   -  1   0   1
4   1  17   1  -   2   0
5  39   1   0  0   -  14
6   0   0  43  1   0   -
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am supposed to make a function called def prittyPrint that takes the dictionary as argument.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
dic = {'1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
    '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
    '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
    '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
    '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
    '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}}

strs = "{0:^2} {1:^2} {2:^2} {3:^2} {4:^2} {5:^2} {6:^2}"    

print strs.format(" ", *sorted(dic))

for x in sorted(dic):
    print strs.format(x, *(dic[x].get(y, '-') for y in sorted(dic)))
```

**output:**

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6 
1  -  1  0  0  1  29
2  13 -  1  0  21 0 
3  0  0  -  1  0  1 
4  1  17 1  -  2  0 
5  39 1  0  0  -  14
6  0  0  43 1  0  -
```

You can also generate the `strs` like this :

```
strs = " ".join("{"+"{0}{1}".format(i, ":^2}") for i in range(7))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the python code which will print the matrix on screen. Call `prettyPrint(data)`.

`table` is a multidimentional array(matrix) with the data.

```
import string

data = {'1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
    '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
    '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
    '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
    '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
    '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}}

def prettyPrint(data):
    count = len(data)

    table = [[0 for x in xrange(count)] for x in xrange(count)]

    print string.ljust(' ', 4),
    for j in range(1, count + 1):
        print string.ljust(`j`, 4),
    print ""

    for i in range(1, count + 1):
        print string.ljust(`i`, 4),

        for j in range(1, count + 1):
            #print string.rjust(`j`, 4),
            if j != i:
                print string.ljust(`data[str(i)][str(j)]`, 4),
                table[i-1][j-1] = data[str(i)][str(j)]
            else:S
                print string.ljust('-', 4),
                table[i-1][j-1] = '-'
        print ""

    print "\nMatrix: \n"
    for row in table:
        print row

prettyPrint(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
     1    2    3    4    5    6    
1    -    1    0    0    1    29   
2    13   -    1    0    21   0    
3    0    0    -    1    0    1    
4    1    17   1    -    2    0    
5    39   1    0    0    -    14   
6    0    0    43   1    0    -    

Matrix: 

[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 29]
[13, 0, 1, 0, 21, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 17, 1, 0, 2, 0]
[39, 1, 0, 0, 0, 14]
[0, 0, 43, 1, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Comment: .Tanks you very much. I need the table i order to find the sequence with least overlaps, it is a part of a LONG exercise.

Comment: Updated answer, table is your matrix... there is '0' instead of '-'.

Comment: i want it to be'-', not '0'. All the number from 1-6 in the table and left sides are the numbers of sequences. From the matrix I can see that only 0 or 1 letter of sequence 4 overlap with any of the other sequences if sequence 4 is the left sequence (The all overlap in the end of eachother. Right end of first sequences overlap with left end of second sequence and so fort.) So from the table i can see that the sequense are supposed to be 4-2-5-1-6-3, and i then need to chain them together.

Comment: @anne I didn't understand your chaining problem, can you explain?

Comment: the number from 1-6 in the top of the matrix, and the number from 1-6 in the left side od the sequences are keys. They represents sequences of letters. The sequences can overlap each other, but the alway overlap in the end (left end of one with the right end of the next one). because the numbers in column 4 is <2 i know that thia is the first sequence. So i need to write a function that returns 4 because that is the key of the only column that have values below 2.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. It's not very pythonic, as I don't use list comprehensions and that kind of stuff, but this way is easier to read and understand:

```
import sys

matrix = {'1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
          '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
          '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
          '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
          '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
          '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}}

#print the column index
sys.stdout.write ("\t") # empty tab at the beginning
for col_index in range (1, len(matrix)+1):
    sys.stdout.write ("%d\t" % col_index)
print ""

# order the matrix rows, using the dictionary keys
for row_index in sorted (matrix.iterkeys()):
    #print the row index
    sys.stdout.write (str(row_index)+"\t")

    # take each row, and order it by its inner key:
    row = matrix[row_index]
    ordered_row = sorted (row.iterkeys())

    # iterate from 1 to number_of_matrix_rows
    for col_index in range (1, len(matrix)+1):
        # if the current column exists as a key in
        # the row, print it. Otherwise, print "-"
        row_item = "-"
        if str(col_index) in ordered_row:
            row_item = row[str(col_index)]
        sys.stdout.write (str(row_item)+"\t")

    # print next row
    print ""
```

Answer (score 2):

A function based on @Ashwini Chaudhary's  solution using `str.format` that can take a dict with variable lenght:

```
def prettyPrint(d,space=5,fill='-'):
    strs = ''.join('{{{0}:^{1}}}'.format(str(i),str(space)) 
                                 for i in xrange(len(d)+1))
    std = sorted(d)
    print strs.format(" ",*std)
    for x in std:
        print strs.format(x,*(d[x].get(y,fill) for y in std)) 

prettyPrint(d)
```

OUT:

```
       1    2    3    4    5    6  
  1    -    1    0    0    1   29  
  2   13    -    1    0   21    0  
  3    0    0    -    1    0    1  
  4    1   17    1    -    2    0  
  5   39    1    0    0    -   14  
  6    0    0   43    1    0    -
```

OR:

```
prettyPrint(d,space=3,fill='0')
```

OUT:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6 
 1  0  1  0  0  1 29 
 2 13  0  1  0 21  0 
 3  0  0  0  1  0  1 
 4  1 17  1  0  2  0 
 5 39  1  0  0  0 14 
 6  0  0 43  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a perfect or most effective solution, but it works:

```
def printMatrix (d):
    # get the amount of characters needed for the maximum number
    numberWidth = len(str(max(max(v.values()) for v in d.values())))

    # function to format the numbers
    formatNumber = lambda x: str(x).rjust(numberWidth)

    keys = sorted(d.keys())
    rows = [' '.join(map(formatNumber, [''] + keys))]

    for r in keys:
        row = [r]
        for k in keys:
            row.append(d[r].get(k, '-'))
        rows.append(' '.join(map(formatNumber, row)))

    print('\n'.join(rows))
```

Used like this:

```
>>> d = { ... }
>>> printMatrix(d)
      1   2   3   4   5   6
  1   -   1   0   0   1  29
  2  13   -   1   0  21   0
  3   0   0   -   1   0   1
  4   1  17   1   -   2   0
  5  39   1   0   0   -  14
  6   0   0  43   1   0   -
```

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner can change your dictionary to a list of list(square matrix):

```
[[d[str(i)].get(str(j), '-') for j in range(1, 7)] for i in range(1, 7)]
```

where `d` is your input dictionary. Based upon that, it's easy to print in any format you desire. BTW, unless this is a school assignment, I don't think printing in any concrete format  really matters. Changing dictionary to matrix-like data structure makes more sense. If just for debug's sake, you can use `pprint` to get a nicer output.

Comment: Thank you. The assignment was to make it more readable, and a matrix would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a verbose and flexible code without external libraries, it also returns an usable matrix.

```
dict_matrix = {'1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
               '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
               '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
               '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
               '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
               '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}}

def matricize_dict(a_dict, x_size, y_size):
    matrix = []

    for i in range(y_size):
        line = []
        for j in range(x_size):
            line.append('-')
        matrix.append(line)

    for i in range(y_size):
        line = dict_matrix[str(i+1)]
        for j in range(x_size):
            try:
                cell = line[str(j+1)]
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                matrix[i][j] = cell
    for item in matrix:
        print(item)

    return matrix

matricize_dict(dict_matrix, 6, 6)
```